# ASPX DetailsView with DDL update to SQL Issue

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Trying to find out if I am approaching this right (NOOB so be patient plz!) I'm trying to write a single aspx page with UserList1 (bind to SQLSource1.displayname) which updates DetailsView1 (Edit Enabled, SQLSource2 where displayname=@displayname). Display name and Dept fields are read-only, yesno needs to updated. If I leave the stock edit textbox it updates fine. End users being end users we want to give them limited options for the update so I want to replace the textbox with a DDL ... Change YESNO field templatefield, add  DDL which has YES or NO option, Postback=enabled.

Unbound I get "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'yesno' ....

Bind("yesno") I get "Conversion from string "YES" to type 'Integer' is not valid"

1st error - I probably need to catch the selected text of the DDL selection to do the update statement ?? Code behind or Javascript/Jquery?

2nd error - why is converting the selection to Integer - SQL column type is text?

TIA Guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The yesno column in your database does not allow nulls

Comment: Column allows NULLs - I managed to sort it out: issue was I was binding on SelectedIndex instead of SelectedValue. Thanx